# is there a pure command-line oauth flow for installed apps?

Tags: google-api-ruby-client

I'm trying to get a pure command line oauth flow for an installed app and it's not easy to piece this together... Docs are sorely lacking... I started with the drive example (https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client-samples/tree/master/drive) but when it gets to `client.authorization = flow.authorize(file_storage)` it tries to start webrick to put up a web page. I need something that works similarly to the CLI tools provided by google: it needs to print out the URL I need to visit and then read in the response that I can copy&paste. Is this possible with the google ruby client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the following monkey-patch works:

```rb
module Google
  class APIClient
    class InstalledAppFlow
      def authorize_cli(storage)
        puts "Please visit: #{@authorization.authorization_uri.to_s}"
        printf "Enter the code: code="
        code = gets
        @authorization.code = code
        @authorization.fetch_access_token!
        if @authorization.access_token
          if storage.respond_to?(:write_credentials)
            storage.write_credentials(@authorization)
          end
          @authorization
        else
          nil
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```